# media notification not showing properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-mediaplayer, android-notification.mediastyle

[buttons are not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP6y9.jpg)

*this are the minSdk 29 and targetSdk 33*

**This is the method for creating the notification.
Am I missing any method that needed to be called? **

```
fun showNotification() {
        val prevIntent =
            Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(Notification.PREVIOUS)
        val prevPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext, 0, prevIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE  )

        val nextIntent =
            Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(Notification.NEXT)
        val nextPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext, 0, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val playPauseIntent =
            Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(Notification.PLAY_PAUSE)
        val playPausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            baseContext,
            0,
            playPauseIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val exitIntent =
            Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(Notification.EXIT)
        val exitPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext, 0, exitIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val fevIntent =
            Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(Notification.FEV)
        val fevPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext, 0, fevIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)


        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Notification.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.app_logo))
            .setStyle(
                androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken)
            ).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentTitle(MusicFiles.getAllData()[MusicFiles.getCurrentPos()].Title)
            .setContentText(MusicFiles.getAllData()[MusicFiles.getCurrentPos()].Artist)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSilent(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.empty_fev , Notification.FEV , fevPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.skip_previous , Notification.PREVIOUS , prevPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.play , Notification.PLAY_PAUSE , playPausePendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.skip_next , Notification.NEXT , nextPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.cross , Notification.EXIT , exitPendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)
    }
```

**I had made BroadcastReceiver to**

```
class NotificationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when(intent?.action){
            Notification.PREVIOUS ->{
                Toast.makeText(context , "prevClicked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            Notification.NEXT ->{
                Toast.makeText(context , "nextClicked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            Notification.PLAY_PAUSE ->{
                Toast.makeText(context , "playPauseClicked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            Notification.EXIT ->{
                Toast.makeText(context , "exitClicked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't know the cause of this problem expecting to know the correct way of creating a media notification